# How can I use Brownie build folder to restore my deployments?

Tags: brownie

I use `brownie bake chainlink-mix` and set the environment, then I run `brownie run scripts/price_feed_scripts/deploy_price_consumer_v3.py --network kovan` and the contract crate successfully，but the corresponding json file is not generated in `build/deployments/42`. Is there anything else I need to configure?

```
scut@scut-VirtualBox:~/chainlink$ brownie run scripts/price_feed_scripts/01_deploy_price_consumer_v3.py --network kovan
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

ChainlinkProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts/price_feed_scripts/01_deploy_price_consumer_v3.py::main'...
Transaction sent: 0xcdc6d882f0e726757fae62a3c68fb90dda358b11415c41a14d82efa7f4c9292f
  Gas price: 2.0 gwei   Gas limit: 147030   Nonce: 10
  PriceFeedConsumer.constructor confirmed   Block: 27664119   Gas used: 133664 (90.91%)
  PriceFeedConsumer deployed at: 0x32D00320C7165aaFBc7996E3df403E826d618d72
```

And then will show

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scut/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/scut/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/scut/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

I think this error is because the transaction has been released, so the program automatically disconnected the link request.It is no actually a error.

When the entire transaction is completed, my `map.json` file is still empty.

```
├── brownie-config.yaml
├── build
│   ├── contracts
│   │   ├── APIConsumer.json
│   │   ├── Counter.json
│   │   ├── dependencies
│   │   │   └── smartcontractkit
│   │   │       └── chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1
│   │   │           ├── AggregatorInterface.json
│   │   │           ├── AggregatorV2V3Interface.json
│   │   │           ├── AggregatorV3Interface.json
│   │   │           ├── BasicToken.json
│   │   │           ├── BufferChainlink.json
│   │   │           ├── CBORChainlink.json
│   │   │           ├── ChainlinkClient.json
│   │   │           ├── Chainlink.json
│   │   │           ├── ChainlinkRequestInterface.json
│   │   │           ├── ENSInterface.json
│   │   │           ├── ENSResolver.json
│   │   │           ├── ERC20Basic.json
│   │   │           ├── ERC20.json
│   │   │           ├── ERC677.json
│   │   │           ├── ERC677Receiver.json
│   │   │           ├── ERC677Token.json
│   │   │           ├── LinkTokenInterface.json
│   │   │           ├── LinkTokenReceiver.json
│   │   │           ├── PointerInterface.json
│   │   │           ├── SafeMathChainlink.json
│   │   │           ├── StandardToken.json
│   │   │           ├── VRFConsumerBase.json
│   │   │           └── VRFRequestIDBase.json
│   │   ├── KeeperCompatibleInterface.json
│   │   ├── LinkToken.json
│   │   ├── MockOracle.json
│   │   ├── MockV3Aggregator.json
│   │   ├── PriceFeedConsumer.json
│   │   ├── VRFConsumer.json
│   │   └── VRFCoordinatorMock.json
│   ├── deployments
│   │   ├── 3
│   │   ├── 42
│   │   ├── dev
│   │   └── map.json
│   ├── interfaces
│   │   ├── KeeperCompatibleInterface.json
│   │   └── LinkTokenInterface.json
│   └── tree.txt
├── contracts
│   ├── APIConsumer.sol
│   ├── Counter.sol
│   ├── PriceFeedConsumer.sol
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── LinkToken.sol
│   │   ├── MockOracle.sol
│   │   ├── MockV3Aggregator.sol
│   │   └── VRFCoordinatorMock.sol
│   └── VRFConsumer.sol
├── img
│   └── chainlink-brownie.png
├── interfaces
│   ├── KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol
│   └── LinkTokenInterface.sol
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── reports
├── requirements.txt
├── scripts
│   ├── chainlink_api_scripts
│   │   ├── 01_deploy_api_consumer.py
│   │   ├── 02_request_api.py
│   │   └── 03_read_data.py
│   ├── deploy_mocks.py
│   ├── helpful_scripts.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── keeper_scripts
│   │   ├── 01_deploy_keeper_counter.py
│   │   ├── 02_check_upkeep.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 01_deploy_keeper_counter.cpython-36.pyc
│   │       ├── 01_deploy_keeper_counter.cpython-37.pyc
│   │       └── 02_check_upkeep.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── price_feed_scripts
│   │   ├── 01_deploy_price_consumer_v3.py
│   │   ├── 02_read_price_feed.py
│   │   ├── 02_read_price_with_ens.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 01_deploy_price_consumer_v3.cpython-36.pyc
│   │       ├── 02_read_price_feed.cpython-36.pyc
│   │       └── 02_read_price_feed.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── helpful_scripts.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── helpful_scripts.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── vrf_scripts
│       ├── 01_deploy_vrf.py
│       ├── 02_request_randomness.py
│       └── 03_read_random_number.py
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── test_api_consumer.py
    ├── test_keeper.py
    ├── test_price_feeds.py
    └── test_vrf.py
```

Comment: Could you update this with what's in your `map.json`? Also, could you please not use screenshots, but instead format the code

Comment: Okay, I have revised my question, please take a look again. There is nothing in my `map.json` file. Is there anything I have overlooked?
If you need more details, please feel free to contact me.Thank you very much.